# Error Writing to File in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, file-io

```
Unhandled exception at 0x102e1cee (msvcr100d.dll) in filename.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00416858 on.
```

The debugging points to line:

```
if (_putc_nolock(ch, f) == EOF)
```

of code

```
#else  /* _UNICODE */
    if (_putc_nolock(ch, f) == EOF)
#endif  /* _UNICODE */
        *pnumwritten = -1;
    else
        ++(*pnumwritten);
}
```

in output.c which I believe is linked in visual studio library. I did not link it.

My code is:

```
body=""
myFile=CreateFile("Sample.txt",FILE_APPEND_DATA,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
BufferNo=sprintf(body,"%.5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f \n",a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8);
WriteFile(myFile,body,lstrlen(body),0,NULL);
CloseHandle(myFile);
```

I initially wrote to file with following lines. I had to write the heading.

```
HANDLE myFile=CreateFile("Sample.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
char* HeadingStr="a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7   a8 \n";
WriteFile(myFile,HeadingStr,lstrlen(HeadingStr),0,NULL);
CloseHandle(myFile);
```

How do I solve this error? Note I have write permission. I ran as administrator, too.
Note that I have already defined BufferNo, myFile, outside the use in last code.

**UPDATE**
I removed `body=""`
Now I get

```
filename.exe triggered a breakpoint.
```

pointing to the file mentioned in comment below.

```
**EDIT**
```

Now, I have problem writing.
Error reads

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7c811384 in stabilo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000 on.
```

and points to line

```
   WriteFile(myFile,body,lstrlen(body),0,NULL);
```

Comment: `body=""` looks strange. You need a buffer to store the string.

Comment: More info needed. How's `body` declared, for instance? Generally, you should post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Comment: I removed that initialisation. Defined body as global variable. Now, it says filename.exe triggered a breakpoint.
and
points to 
{
    __debugbreak();
}

in file dbgrptt.c

Comment: I declared body as char* body. but got new error.

Comment: A global `char *body` will have zero storage assigned to it. Make it, like my answer says, `char body[1000];`, and you can write 1000 characters to it. Which is probably more than your values will need. Using `char *body` will just give you a NULL pointer, which is the cause of an assert in the Runtime library.

Comment: For future reference, your stack trace is inside msvcr100d.dll, which means you called a C Standard Library function incorrectly.  So don't look at WinAPI functions, or put "WINAPI" in the title of your question.  And if you'd known this, it would have been a strong hint that file write permissions weren't the problem either.

Comment: Anyway, why are you mixing C++ Standard Library and Windows API like this?  You could have used `fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fscanf`.  Then the Standard Library would have taken care of having a buffer of the correct size.

Comment: This question is too localized and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: `Access violation writing location 0x00000000` points to `body` being `null`. Since its a pointer declared at file scope, it will start of as `null` (zero initialized). Do you ever change its value?

Comment: @jerry thanks for your comment. already solved it. It seems I cannot 0 and null at the same time. it was answered in another question.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done IO using the Windows API directly, but the MSDN documentation does support that. The question, then, is why does your first call to `WriteFile` (for the header) work when it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: see this: It's something to writing at same location. twice. Note, second one has loop.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407948/writing-multiple-lines-within-loop?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `body` in this section is incorrect.

```
body="";
...
BufferNo=sprintf(body,"%.5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f %[3].5f\n",
                      a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8);
```

Presumably it's a `char *` (alhtough I'm just guessing), which means you are trying to write a bunch of number values to a constant string capable of holding exactly zero characters. Since it's a constant, it's non-writeable.

Change it to `char body[1000];` or something similar.

Comment: Ha, missed that first line. Good catch.

Comment: And if all numbers are close to DBL_MAX, guess what happens.

Comment: No, all the numbers are double only. BUT, Still, the debugger points to WriteFile. any opinion?

Comment: If you mean that the debugger shows the line with `WriteFile` as the line where the code will execute when it comes back from `sprintf`, then that would be correct. But I'm 100% sure that my answer describes a problem in your code. I'm not saying you can't have OTHER problems in the code, including ones that cause WriteFile to go wrong.

Comment: No, I am really grateful for your help. I was also wondering if you could give a helping hand with this new error. This is new error. The debugger is pointing to this as error. I have updated my question.

Comment: Your original post says that code works fine - what did you change?

Comment: I don't remember saying the code works fine. If I ever said, may be I meant, that the error is not pointed to buffer. But to WriteFile. There is no change, actually. (sorry for unaccepting your answer. I guess people do not read accepted posts. so!)

Comment: So, if you JUST write the header (comment out the other code), what happens? Because your original post says "I initially wrote to file with following lines. I had to write the heading.", which implies to me that the code posted immediately below that works.

Comment: Yes, writing heading still workd. Problem is not with writing heading. It's not WriteFile for heading but for body where error lie. When I execute code, it shows error. If I check folder, there is file named as defined and with header line but without the remaining of what I expect because the WriteFile for body is not writing. My bad. edited the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32686/discussion-between-user2178841-and-mats-petersson)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sprintf` overruns the buffer for sure. Even worse: you try to write over a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could not understand what you mean. If I removed the string declaration body="" and defined as char* body, and directly use, is it supposed to remove error?

Comment: if it was a char[10000] this problem might go away, but until you learn at least the most basic things you only put the world in danger.

Comment: Yes, still I am still learning basics. It's been less than a few weeks since I started C (2 actually). I had to speed up, it's like complication. :)