# Writing Multiple Lines within Loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have declared

```
char body[1000] ;
HANDLE myFile;
```

I already have a previous section where I create a file and write the title. It writes well.

It has following commands without loop.

```
HANDLE myFile=CreateFile("filename.txt",GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,CREATE_NEW,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
char* HeadingStr="a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 \n";
WriteFile(myFile,HeadingStr,lstrlen(HeadingStr),0,NULL);
CloseHandle(myFile);
```

Then I have following code

```
loop{ (100 times)

myFile=CreateFile("filename.txt",FILE_APPEND_DATA,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
BufferNo=sprintf(body,"%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f \n",a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8);
WriteFile(myFile,body,BufferNo,0,NULL);
CloseHandle(myFile);

}
```

The loop is actually a message I am receiving from a device. So, that does not have to do anything to this.

After running the code, The error Access Violation Error and pointing to

```
WriteFile(myFile,body,BufferNo,0,NULL);
```

If I check the file, I get

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 (rectangle: may be way of text editor saying line break) and then 2 4 23 21 12 431 23 32 (same rectangle)
```

This is all. The error notes that this is not due to message coming from device.
If you need further details, let me know.
Where in here lies the error?

P.S. I asked a question prior to this. that contained error before this error occured and also contained solution tothat problem. I asked there but due to inactivity, I am asking again. Problems are different though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404683/error-writing-to-file-in-visual-studio?rq=1

Comment: Please post ALL of your code [at least enough of it to be a complete piece that can be compiled], since the actual lines you have posted so far don't actually show anything wrong.

Comment: This question is too localized and unlikely to ever help a future visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WriteFile prototype:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_         HANDLE hFile,
  _In_         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

`lpNumberOfBytesWritten` and `lpOverlapped` cannot both be `NULL`.
Since you're passing `0` for `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` whilst `lpOverlapped` is `NULL`, it's trying to write to address location `0`, which causes the exception.

Give it a dummy variable.

```
...
DWORD dummy = 0;
WriteFile(myFile,body,BufferNo,&dummy,NULL);
...
```

You should also move the `CreateFile(...)` and `CloseHandle(...)` outside of the loop block (no need to repeatedly open and close the file).

Comment: thanks. hope it works. I initially started as such (open/close) outside loop. that did not even let write single line.

Comment: actually what is the difference between using 0 directly and using zero after defining as reference. these two?

Comment: The parameter takes a pointer to the value, not the value itself. Earlier you were passing 0 as a pointer; 0 is an invalid memory address. In my example, you create a DWORD value on the stack and pass the *address* of that to `WriteFile` (hence the `&`). `WriteFile` will overwrite the value of `dummy` with its own value (the number of bytes written by the function). A value of 0 is equivalent to the null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be interesting to read code of your function WriteFile().

Anyway, the usual algorithm for the kind of computation you try to do is:

- open file
- write lines (loop if needed)
- close file

instead of

- open file, write, close
- open file, write, close
- ...

So, I suppose the best is to write a pre-function to open your file, and remove this action from WriteFile().

Comment: `WriteFile` is part of the Win32 API. It is well documented on MSDN.